# Is it possible to retry a VS Test build step in Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online) after the step has failed?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-devops

In TeamCity it is possible to do this, but I cannot see an option in Team Services. I have a few tests that connect to live DB's and site deployments and as they have just been deployed so can take a bit of time to warm up. I know I can add in some code in my tests to do the warm up, but I would rather have the step retry if it's possible.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this approach. 1) Unit tests should NEVER fail. 2) Unit tests should be self-contained. You really should write mock classes and an object factory implementation to instantiate the proper class given a particular situation. I.e. for database calls, instead of using a `DataConnection` or `DataCommand` class implementation, code for `IDbConnection` or `IDbCommand`. Then you can implement those interfaces in your mock class and pass that to force a return of specific data.

Comment: They aren't unit tests, they are 'sort of' integration tests that check disparate parts of the system are hooked up correctly

Comment: Most likely there's no option like this in VSO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSO does not provide any option to rerun the failed Build Test step in Build Process.

Comment: I have come to this conclusion also - I sorted the issue by deleting the offending tests!